# Apache won't start laravel with alias

Tags: laravel, apache

I installed a apache server on my computer and it says "it works"in localhost, I gave a directory and a alias in httpd.conf file to my laravel public folder, but when ı go to that alias, it won't show the laravel page, but it shows the files inside the public folder.
I used "php artisan serve" and it opens in localhost:8000, but I want that in alias page, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP, your project should be in your **htdocs** folder, and you need to edit your **httpd-vhosts.conf** and add something along these lines.

```
<VirtualHost alias.test:80>
    
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/your_folder_name/public"
    ServerName alias.test
    
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to add your alias to your hosts file (**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**):

```
127.0.0.1 alias.test
```